# C# Package not found on build even after installing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, build, json.net

I installed the Newtonsoft.Json package through terminal on VS Code. On running the command "dotnet run" I get the error message:

> "The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found"

together with other associated error messages.

How would I address this issue? Thanks

Comment: `dotnet restore`?

Comment: II tried that command and I got the same error.

Comment: How did you install it? Is it mentioned in your .csproj file? An `<ItemGroup>` in your .csproj file should have a child that looks something like this (version number may be different): `<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />`

Comment: I had installed it using the following command: "install-package Newtonsoft.Json -Scope CurrentUser"

In checking the .csproj file, I found no child sections mentioning the Newtonsoft package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try run `dotnet build` first then `dotnet run`.

> The command depends on the dotnet build command to build the code.
>    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore30

Comment: Thanks, but I tried "dotnet build" and got the same error as when I ran "dotnet run".

Comment: Can you paste a snippet of the errors? It might help with finding the solution to your problem.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Please refer to my answer above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on [John's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/john) questions above, I found that my installation may have been faulty, so I used "dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json" to install Newsoft.

Upon restarting VS Code, I found that the errors had disappeared. My sincerest thanks to everyone here in helping me solve this issue.